# shopify.api_version.VersionNotFoundError Python

Tags: python-3.x, oauth-2.0, shopify, fastapi

I am integrating Shopify with FastAPI to create REST API Endpoints. Currently, I am trying to authorize the seller using the app. Here's the code.

```
# Endpoint to authenticate a seller
@router.post("/authorize", response_class=ORJSONResponse)
def authorize_seller(auth_data: SellerAuth):

    # Start a Shopify session
    shopify.Session.setup(api_key=os.getenv("SHOPIFY_CLIENT_ID"), secret=os.getenv("SHOPIFY_CLIENT_SECRET"))
    
    shop_url = "c56-test-seller.myshopify.com"
    api_version = '2023-07'
    state = binascii.b2a_hex(os.urandom(15)).decode("utf-8")
    # redirect_uri = "http://myapp.com/auth/shopify/callback"
    redirect_uri = "http://127.0.0.1:8082"
    scopes = ['read_products', 'read_orders']

    newSession = shopify.Session(shop_url, api_version)
    auth_url = newSession.create_permission_url(scopes, redirect_uri, state)

    return ORJSONResponse(
        status_code=response_status.HTTP_200_OK,
        content=jsonable_encoder({"auth_url": auth_url}),
    )
```

However, I am getting an `shopify.api_version.VersionNotFoundError`. I have added the redirect_uri to the urls list on my partner dashboard as well. The error trace is telling me that the version is not found  even though it it the current stable release.

```
return cls.versions[version]
KeyError: '2023-07'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the version of the shopify_python_api package you are using (which is current at the time of this writing) doesn't yet support that specific API version.

https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_python_api/blob/master/shopify/api_version.py

```
@classmethod
    def define_known_versions(cls):
        cls.define_version(Unstable())
        cls.define_version(Release("2021-10"))
        cls.define_version(Release("2022-01"))
        cls.define_version(Release("2022-04"))
        cls.define_version(Release("2022-07"))
        cls.define_version(Release("2022-10"))
        cls.define_version(Release("2023-01"))
        cls.define_version(Release("2023-04"))
```

You could try using one of the supported versions or wait until they incorporate the `2023-07` version in the python package.

Comment: Yes, I found out that Python SDK is outdated and changed the version but your answer is correct. Thanks!